# How can I access the Gateways services?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I have been trying to access `craft\commerce\services\Gateways;` from a plugin but I can't figure out how I need to access it. I've used the following:

```
$gateways = Commerce::getInstance()->commerce->getAllGateways();

$gateways = craft\commerce\services\Gateways::getAllGateways();
```

The first one says `Getting unknown property: craft\commerce\Plugin::commerce` and the second one tells me 
`Non-static method craft\commerce\services\Gateways::getAllGateways() should not be called statically`

Can anyone tell me the proper way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
use craft\commerce\Plugin as Commerce;


$gatewayService = Commerce::getInstance()->getGateways();
$variables = [
    'gateways' => $gatewayService->getAllGateways(),
];
```

Comment: FYI: This pattern is a product of Plugins being "singleton" classes, and their instances having Services attached as [components](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-components), sometimes with special "getter" methods (i.e. `->getGateways()`). In most Plugins, it's safe to try `MyPlugin::getInstance()->serviceName->methodName();`

Comment: So, this probably would have worked as well and I just didn't think of it? `$gateways = Commerce::getInstance()->commerce->getGateways()->getAllGateways();`?

Comment: No, you've already got a reference to the plugin instance from `Commerce::getInstance()`—the `commerce` property wouldn't exist. Just `Commerce::getInstance()->getGateways()->getAllGateways()` will do!

You might be thinking of the way you get access to Commerce services via Twig (`{% set gateways = craft.commerce.gateways.getAllGateways() %}`, but this is specific to the templating environment (`craft` is just a variable that you can hang functionality on, and a lot of plugins attach their singleton instance there).